# File persistence in apache

Tags: linux, apache

I am running a website xyz.com and using apache as web server. 
In the document root whenever I create a test file , i am able to access it via the application URL - 
xyz.com/sandbox/test_file

However , if i delete the test file and still go to the URL xyz.com/sandbox/test_file , I can still see the contents of the file that is supposed to be deleted. 
I checked with Filezilla and Putty and the file IS in fact DELETED and not there but I can still open the file contents. 
Any assistance here would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance for your help :)

CentOS release 6.7 
Apache/2.2.15

Comment: do you use a proxy (like squid etc) to access your website? try _tail_ the apache's access_log (usually in _/usr/local/apache/logs/access\_log_) and then hit the url again, see if it's really hit the server or it's not from the apache

Comment: @David
No proxies.. The access log shows lines like - ######## - - [17/Nov/2015:02:15:04 +0000] "GET  /sandbox/test_file1.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"

Comment: your apache's access log give status 404 (not found). you should not receive the file, is it your browser cache? try hitting _ctrl + f5_ to refresh the page

Comment: if I do a refresh on the same page , i get the 404 error , document not found. But if i open the same link say xyz.com/sandbox/test_file1.txt in a new tab or browser window , I can see the old file contents even though the file is technically deleted from the system.
FYI I have cleared browser caches and open the file in incognito mode

Comment: Also , if i open the page in a different browser , i can see the file contents

Comment: have you try open it using another network connection? please try my suggestion bellow

Answer (score 0):

try adding this *.htaccess* in your sandbox directory, this should stop any proxies and browser to cache your file.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php|txt)>
    ExpiresDefault A0
    FileETag None
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

first please check whether if the web server has both mod_expires and mod_headers enabled. you should see in your httpd.conf :

```
LoadModule headers_module lib/modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
```

if it's still not loaded, then load it and restart the apache service.

Comment: Tried it..but I can still see the deleted file contents :(

Comment: hmm, your web server doesn't give the file (it return 404) , you've clear the browser cache so it should not the problem. After putting the _.htaccess_ above, could you try create new file, etc test_file_again.txt, access it from browser, delete the file and then access it again from browser